Blob-triggered function works locally but not deployed (not invoked)
Got a function working locally, triggered when a file is dropped and now deploying to azure.
Function signature looks like this.  Notice the binding expression.
This expression is attempting to pull a value from appsettings called "MyFolderPath"
Locally this works as expected.  The path is container/folder_name
The setting is available in azure under Environment variables.
However, when I drop a new file in that path, the function is not triggered or invoked.
What can I check?
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("%MyFolderPath%/{name}",Connection = "FuncStorage", Stream stream, string name)


Initially I was getting same issue. but, after adding the storage connection string in function app environment variables working as expected.

while adding the connection string in environment variable name and value must be same in portal and local.
After adding the connection string need to redeploy the function.


I have created blob trigger function with run time stack .NET 8.0.
The function got triggered when i uploaded blobs in container.
Function code:
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

    public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function(nameof(Function1))]
    public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("hello32/{name}", Connection = "Connection23")] Stream stream, string name)
    {
        using var blobStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var content = await blobStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {content}");
    }
}

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "Connection23": "your-storage conn-string"
  }
}


I have published the function into azure portal successfully. check below:

When I uploaded the blobs in container the function got triggered in portal as well. check the below traces:

Below are uploaded blobs in storage container.


Thank you.  I thought I had checked over the local settings vs the deployed settings/ environment vars, but sure enough there was a difference.  Once corrected, things started working as expected.
